# Insert using Scope Identity as Attribute

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When creating `User`, I need to give it a system `Role`, so I was wondering what is the best way to do that.

I have working solution, but I'm unsure if it's the best way.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Users (Name, Email, Username, Password, Active) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Username, @Password, @Active); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", user._Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user._Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user._Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 1);

            user_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {                   
            //Handle Exception
        }
    }
}

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User_Role (User_Role_User_Id, User_Role_Role_Id) VALUES (@User_ID, @Role_ID)", con))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", user_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role_ID", user.Role_ID);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
     }
}
```

Now my problem is, if adding the role goes wrong for whatever reason, I'll have a user created without a role.

So I was wondering if it's possible to join the two `SqlCommand`, considering that I need the `Scope_Identity` for the insert into `User_Role`. Or do a rollback on the last exception catch for both Insert's?

Comment: Create a stored procedure that does it all in a single transaction. One fails, both fail.

Comment: +1 to the stored proc approach. As a different approach, what is unique for the user table?  `Email`?  If so, you can change your `INSERT INTO User_Role` statement to `select User_Id from Users where Email = @Email`. If the user insert failed, then that `Email` wouldn't be in the user table therefore not inserting any data into the role join table.

Comment: Tried creating a stored procedure and worked. Never thought of that since I've never used/created one.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either make a stored procedure that does the work as an atomic unit, or if you are unable to do that, you can wrap the entire code block in a transaction if yo keep using the same connection, like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        //Run first command

        //Run second command

        //If we have succeeded, commit the transaction
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch()
    {
        //Something went wrong, roll back
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried creating a stored procedure and worked. Never thought of that since I've never used/created one.
Although I'll be able to use the transaction on other areas.